# SQL Not Exists in this Query - is it possible

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my script - it simply looks for the image file associated with a person row.

Now the error will display if there is NO .jpg evident when the query runs:

> *Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\Dev\ClientServices\Defence\RAN\Shore\Config\Photos\002054.2009469432270600.001.jpg" does not exist.*

Is there a way to write this query to

```
IF not exists then set id_number = '002054.2009469432270427.001'
```

so it will always display this photo for any rows without a picture.

```
ALTER
procedure [dbo].[as_ngn_sp_REP_PH108_photo] (@PMKEYS nvarchar(50)) 
AS
---exec [as_ngn_sp_REP_PH108_photo] '8550733'
SET 
NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @PATH AS NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ID_NUMBER NVARCHAR(27)
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

EXEC DB_GET_DB_SETTING'STAFF PICTURE FILE LOCATION', 0, @PATH OUTPUT 

IF RIGHT(@PATH,1) <> '\'

    SET @PATH = @PATH + '\' 

SELECT @ID_NUMBER = ID_NUMBER FROM aView_person WHERE EXTRA_CODE_1 = @PMKEYS

SET @PATH = @PATH + @ID_NUMBER + '.jpg'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ''Picture1'' [Picture], BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk ''' + REPLACE(@PATH,'''','''''') + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS RAN'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change you code to work as follows:

```
SET @PATH = @PATH + isnull(@ID_NUMBER,'002054.2009469432270427.001') + '.jpg'
```

If @Id_Number isn't found the value would be null, so we replace null with the default id.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to check file existence in SQL Server. Find below post to know how it is possible in SQL Server. This guy using in built **xp_fileexist** stored procedure to get work around.

**[File Validation in SQL Server with xp_fileexist stored procedure](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1272/file-validation-in-sql-server-with-xpfileexist-stored-procedure/)**

Good Luck !!

Comment: You need to distinguish two cases: file names not set, and files not present.